# Creating an object for click and dragging as oppose to repeated code for multiple drag sources.

Tags: vb.net, oop, drag-and-drop

I am currently developing a project in which part of its functionality consists of a timeline where the user can drag and drop dates to their corresponding events and vice versa. The dates and events are images.

The system currently works by repeating code for every "image source" and "drag location". I have six different image sources and hence repeat this code 6 times.

(code for initiating the click and drag)
`If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
            Dim source As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
            PicDragSource.DoDragDrop(source.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End If`

(code for the empty picture box to receive the image copy)

```
   Dim bm As Bitmap = DirectCast(
    e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True), Bitmap)
    PicDropTarget.Image = bm
```

Is there a way to replicate this using object oriented methods to make my code a bit more elegant as appose to the CTRL + C, CTRL + V state it is currently in? My experience with VB and OOP is very limited but i would like to add another level of complexity to my project.

I apologise for any ignorance in advance,
cheers

(code above taken from [this website](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_drag_drop_image.html) for my student project)

Comment: Is the project for a VB class (where you might be expected to know and use specific techniques)?

Comment: It's for a computer science class. The project can be developed in any language. I decided to do it in VB and feel like I've picked it up quite quickly however my experience is still quite limited

Comment: Depending on the details, this might fit in a class, or it might fit in a function within a form.  You might need to make it generic to have type safety and avoid working through `Object` with late binding.  Partly that depends on whether the image source is the same type every time (likewise for the drag target), or if it varies, whether it at least conforms to a single interface---generics wouldn't buy you anything if you can't constrain the generic type to a base class or interface.

Comment: the clicking and dragging actions all take place within a single child form. Each picture drag source changes the value of a variable and once it is dropped into any drag target the variable is compared. (eg: when left mouse is down on DragSource1, x becomes equal to 1, When the image is dragged into DropTarget1, if x = 1 then the correct date and event have been matched up. This is the only difference between each CTRL+C CTRL+V of the code

Comment: the image source is a different photo which is saved in the visual studio resources.

Comment: I would start by factoring the common code out into functions.  You'll probably still have multiple event handlers---I don't have a lot of familiarity with drag and drop, so I'm not sure if you need separate handlers for the drag and the drop---and then each of them would call out to your common functions.  There would still be some repeated code, but it would be reduced to single function calls.